# LINQ-to-entities - Null reference

Tags: c#, linq, null, linq-to-entities

I could swear this was working the other day:

```
var resultSet =
    (from o in _entities.Table1
     where o.Table2.Table3.SomeColumn == SomeProperty
     select o
    ).First();
SelectedItem = resultSet.Table2.SomeOtherColumn;
```

I am getting a null reference exception on the last line: resultSet.Table2 is null.
Not only am I sure that all the foreign keys and whatnot have the correct values, but I don't see how Table2 **could** be null, since `o.Table2.Table3.SomeColumn == SomeProperty`.

**resultSet has all the correct values**, with the exception that Table2 is null.

<strike>**[Edit]**  This works:</strike>

```
SelectedItem = _entities.Table2.First(
    o => o.Table2.SomeColumn == SomeProperty).SomeOtherColumn;
```

And, above, `resultSet` has all the correct values, so it is not a problem with the data in the database; LINQ-to-entities is simply doing something wrong.

Comment: I think you should add code that gets Table2 since the problem is in the extraction of it, not int the query.

Comment: @Andrew: But resultSet.Table2 should point to the resultSet's (only) referenced Table2 row, shouldn't it?  I've done this before with no problems, and I'm fairly certain that's what it's there for...

Comment: If the Table1 is empty, the "where o.Table2.Table3.SomeColumn..." will not be executed, so theoretically Table2 may be a null.

Comment: None of the tables are empty; and as I said, all the references have been verified to be correct, and all the other values of resultSet are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> LINQ-to-entities is simply doing something wrong.

No, it's working as designed. L2E will only `JOIN` in tables when you force it to. This improves performance. As long as you are in L2E, you can reference any relationship. That's why this works:

```
SelectedItem = _entities.Table2.First(
    o => o.Table2.SomeColumn == SomeProperty).SomeOtherColumn;
```

Your lambda expression here will be interpreted by LINQ to Entities, and converted to SQL. On the other hand, this:

```
var resultSet =
    (from o in _entities.Table1
     where o.Table2.Table3.SomeColumn == SomeProperty
     select o
    ).First();
SelectedItem = resultSet.Table2.SomeOtherColumn;
```

...gives a result of type `Table1`. You are now in object space. Since your query does not force `Table2` to be loaded, L2E won't generate SQL columns for it. This results in more efficient SQL when you don't need `Table2`. When you do, you have to say so:

```
var resultSet =
    (from o in _entities.Table1.Include("Table2")
     where o.Table2.Table3.SomeColumn == SomeProperty
     select o
    ).First();

SelectedItem = resultSet.Table2.SomeOtherColumn;
```

This will work. **However**, your `First(lambda)` method above is *a better solution*. (Compare the SQL.)

Comment: I just realized my second query gave the *wrong* results, since Table2->Table3 is One->Many (I want the *one* used by Table1).  Your `.Include()` fixed the problem, though; thanks!

Comment: For future googlers: see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Answer (score 0):

.First may not be returning anything.  Are you sure that the value of SomeProperty exists in SomeColumn on your dataset?

Wrap the whole thing in an if using .Any() to determine if you have a record, or test for null on the resultSet.Table2

Comment: If this is the case, then it's a bug. First is supposed to throw if the sequence is empty.

Comment: No, as I said, all the properties of resultSet have the correct values except for Table2, which is null